# How to set a default value to an <input/> element, formatted with Cleave.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cleave

I've tried to set default value by setting a `value` property:

```
new Cleave('.cleave-input-class-name', {
                time: true,
                timePattern: ['h', 'm']
            });
$(.cleave-input-class-name).value = '09:00';
```

Also I tried to do it without jQuery, it didn't work as well. How to set a default value to a Cleave-formatted input element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing JS's native `value` assignment with jQuery, which won't work. Instead you'd use [val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/). You also need to inclose your selector in quotes (may have been intentional):

```
$('.cleave-input-class-name').val('09:00');
```

Comment: @majorMobilych Great! Please don't forget to mark this as the correct answer.